# TSQL Cursor error in FETCH NEXT - Fixed when executed second time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am running a script in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 that involves a cursor. The script will go through a database table row-by-row, and combine data into single rows inserted into a second database table. I am confident that a cursor is the best way to go about this.

I have an issue that does not seems to be related to my code, because when it occurs, my only solution is to simply re-executed the code, and the error will not occur again.

I have pinpointed the error to the following:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @theCursor INTO @variable, @anotherVariable, @etc...
```

The following error will occur

> Could not complete cursor operation because the set options have changed since the cursor was declared.

Again, the extremely confusing problem is that this will not occur if I re-run the script after getting this error. I create a new query on the database, and I get the error *every time*. I then re-run the script, and it will work *every time*.

Another strange thing is that the error will only occur after this `FETCH` line has been executed about five times!

I have tried catching the error and simply re-invoking the entire procedure, but the error keeps occurring. The *only solution* I know of is to run the script again via SQL Server's 'Execute' command (F5 on keyboard).

I know there is not much here to go on. I myself do not have much to go on in specifics.

Comment: Please post the relevant code that defines, opens, reads, closes, and deallocates the cursor.

Comment: The error does tell you the problem - `SET` options have been changed.  And of course if you re-run on the same connection the problem doesn't reappear - the `SET` options stay in force until something changes them to a different value.

Comment: You may try to `DEALLOCATE CURSOR`.

Comment: I would like to thank the three of you very much for your attention and willingness to help. I have found a solution, and I have posted it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that I didn't know what types of things could be regarded as 'SET options', and what impact they could have.

In my script, I play around with the **dateformat**, as to deal with some inconsistent data in the database tables. It goes something like this:

```
set dateformat mdy 
/* Do some DATETIME stuff with current format... */
set dateformat ymd 
// ...
set dateformat dmy
// ...
set dateformat ymd 
// ...
```

The solution was to not leave the **dateformat** as ymd, as I do above. Simply adding a `set dateformat mdy` at the end of all my date format shenanigans prevents the error from ever occurring. Strangely enough, ending off with `set dateformat dmy` does not work, but `set dateformat mdy` does.